# Simple 1 bit register

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am trying to write a 1 bit shift register with this code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register is
   port(
      clk      : in  std_logic;
      reset      : in  std_logic;
      shiftin : in std_logic;
      shiftout : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
      );

end simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register;

architecture simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register_behavior of simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register is 

    signal shiftreg : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);   

begin
process (clk,reset) 
    begin  
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            shiftreg <= shiftreg(30 downto 0) & shiftin;
        end if;    
end process;
shiftout <= shiftreg(31);
end simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register_behavior;
```

but when simulating I get the errors

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-925] indexed name is not a std_logic_vector [C:/Users/Darren/Desktop/project_6_1_3/project_6_1_3.srcs/sources_1/new/1Bit_delay_register.vhd:28]
```

but they both are vectors and I cant seem to find much on this problem

Edit : Testbench

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

Entity one_bit_shift_tb is
end one_bit_shift_tb;

architecture behaviour of one_bit_shift_tb is
    component simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register
   port(
          clk      : in  std_logic;
          shiftin : in std_logic;
          shiftout : out std_logic
          );
    end component;


    signal clk: STD_LOGIC;
    signal shiftreg : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal shiftin : std_logic;
    signal shiftout : std_logic;

begin
    u_shifter: simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register 
    port map (clk =>clk, shiftin => shiftin, shiftout => shiftout);    
    process
    begin
        clk <='0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <='1';
        wait for 5 ns;
    end process;    
    process    
    begin             
        shiftin <='0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        shiftin <='1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        shiftin <='0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        shiftin <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end behaviour;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to push in a `std_logic_vector` with two elements (`shiftout : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)`) one single element.

Try to declare it as a `std_logic` or a `std_logic_vector(0 to 0)`.

Even if... Why do you need a 1-element vector?

Comment: ah I see now, still isnt simulating but at least my top level is working ! It's for labs for uni, i missed a few classes and trying to catch up at home but there seems so little information regarding vhdl specifics like this.

Comment: Well, you did not write the "code" for the reset. Besides this.. What does not work?

Comment: Yeah the reset was not needed after all I thought I might have needed it for the testbench.  http://imgur.com/8u97u7V that is the output simulation but it doesnt seem right. I'll edit in my testbench

Comment: Can you see the "U" in the shiftreg? I think they are "Unknown" values. THAT is what reset is for, so I assume it is needed ;) try implementing it (it's really trivial) and then raise the reset for a couple of cycles, then start counting. I think it'll work

Answer (score 2):

Looking at these two lines:

```
shiftout : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
```

and

```
shiftout <= shiftreg(31);
```

The first declares `shiftout` as being two bits wide. The second tries to assign to this a one-bit value. Your two options are:

Redfine `shiftout` to be one bit wide:

```
shiftout : out std_logic
```

or change the assignment to match the output width:

```
shiftout <= shiftreg(31 downto 30);
```

I suspect you want to do the first of these two options.